# Make the probability largest

Tags: probability

We have a box that contents of n ($n\gt1000)$balls, which are all identical. We get 1000 balls from the box randomly and mark them. Then put them back to the box and pick up 150 balls randomly. Assume that there are x balls that are marked among the 150 balls. Please find out n that make the probability P(x=10) largest. 
I know that $P(x=10)={\frac{\binom{1000}{10}\binom{n-1000}{140}}{\binom{n}{150}}}$. But calculating the exact n that makes $P(x=10)$ largest from this function is very difficult. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_n=P(x=10)$ when there are $n$ balls, that is,
$$
p_n=\frac{\binom{1000}{10}\binom{n-1000}{140}}{\binom{n}{150}}=c\frac{(n-1000)!(n-150)!}{(n-1140)!n!},
$$
where $c$ does not depend on $n$, and
$$
\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=\frac{(n-999)(n-149)}{(n-1139)(n+1)},
$$
from which one sees that $p_n-p_{n+1}$ has the sign of
$$
(n-1139)(n+1)-(n-999)(n-149)=10n-1139-999\cdot149=2\cdot(n-14999).
$$
Thus, the sequence $(p_n)$ is increasing on $n\leqslant14999$, decreasing on $n\geqslant15000$, and maximum at $n=14999$ and $n=15000$.

---

More generally, if one marks $m$ balls amongst $n$ and one finds $a$ marked balls amongst $b$ balls drawn randomly, then
$$
\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=\frac{(n-m+1)(n-b+1)}{(n-m-b+a+1)(n+1)},
$$
thus $p_n-p_{n+1}$ has the sign of
$$
(n-m-b+a+1)(n+1)-(n-m+1)(n-b+1)=a\cdot(n-(mb/a)+1).
$$
If $mb/a=r$ is an integer, $p_n$ is maximum at $n=r-1$ and at $n=r$ (this is the case of the question). Otherwise, $p_n$ is maximum at the unique $n$ such that $r-1\lt n\lt r$, that is, at $n=\lfloor r\rfloor$. In every case, the set of solutions is
$$
[r-1,r]\cap\mathbb N.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Lets just take an intuitive approach:
You want $10$ out of $150$ balls to be marked, so thats $\frac 1{15}$ of all balls. You mark $1000$ balls, so you would expect $n$ to be $15000$. Now, we calculate $P(x=10)$ for $n=14998$, $n=14999$, $15000$ and $15001$. This gives that the probability is maximal for $n=14999$ and $n=15000$. I don't see why it is optimal for $14999$ too, but that's what mathematica tells me.

Comment: Exactly, the average expect valued IS the single value with the maximum probability. That's why it's called the average...